# Elixir/Phoenix sum of the column

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I'm trying to get the sum of the particular column.
I have a schema of orders, with the field total, that stores the total price.
Now I'm trying to created a query that will sum total value of all the orders, however not sure if I'm doing it right. 
Here is what i have so far:

```
def create(conn, %{"statistic" => %{"date_from" => %{"day" => day_from, "month" => month_from, "year" => year_from}}}) do

date_from = Ecto.DateTime.cast!({{year_from, month_from, day_from}, {0, 0, 0, 0}})
revenue = Repo.all(from p in Order, where: p.inserted_at >= ^date_from, select: sum(p.total))

render(conn, "result.html", revenue: revenue)
end
```

And just calling it like `<%= @revenue %>` in the html.eex. 
As of right now, it doesn't return errors, just renders random symbol on the page, instead of the total revenue.

I think my query is wrong, but couldn't find good information about how to make it work properly. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ecto are you using?

Comment: Try `Repo.one` instead of `Repo.all`.

Comment: @Dogbert damn, can't believe I made this mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query returns just 1 value, and `Repo.all` wraps it in a list. When you print a list using `<%= ... %>`, it treats integers inside the list as Unicode codepoints, and you get the character with that codepoint as output on the page. The fix is to use `Repo.one` instead, which will return the value directly, which in this case is an integer.

```
revenue = Repo.one(from p in Order, where: p.inserted_at >= ^date_from, select: sum(p.total))
```

Comment: Oh, that's why I was getting different symbols instead of the value. Thank for elaborating!

Answer (score 4):

@Dogbert's answer is correct. It is worth noting that if you are using Ecto 2.0 (currently in release candidate) then you can use [Repo.aggregate/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.0-rc.5/Ecto.Repo.html#c:aggregate/4):

```
revenue = Repo.aggregate(from p in Order, where: p.inserted_at >= ^date_from, :sum, :total)
```